# Html.listboxfor() how to capture event on change/add item - Jquery MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a requirement where I want to capture when an item is added to the listbox in MVC C#. There are two listboxes, one for available items and another for selected and I'm using buttons for adding items from available to selected. I can't use button events as they're written generically for multiple screens. So I need something like change event of selected listbox so I can perform a specific action.

I can't seem to find why the `change` event isn't working.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model?.SelectedValues, "Code", "Description"), new 
{ 
  @style ="width:300px; ", 
  size = 20, 
  name = "All", 
  @class = "evo-no-padding-right" 
})
```

```js
$('#SelectedValues').change(function () {
  const selected = $("#SelectedValues");
  if (selected.length > 0) {
    $("#" + selected).width = "300px";
  } else {
    $("#" + selected).width = "260px";
  }
});
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture when an item is **added** to the listbox'? Do you mean that you're dynamically creating elements, or instead you want to know when a user selects something? It would also help to see the actual HTML output.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 list boxes. One has a list of available items and on button clicks I add to this second (selected) listbox.

Comment: Change should work when list item selection is changes. it would not work when an item it added to list. You can write your event code after adding item in the list itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery is invalid. You don't need to append a hash when calling your selector again.

```
const selected = $("#SelectedValues");
if (selected.length > 0) {
    $(selected).css("width", "300px");
} else {
    $(selected).css("width", "260px");
}
```

Comment: He could also use `$(this)` instead as he is in a callback?